# Need to call function of another controller from current? Is that a right approach?

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5.7

I have fresh laravel 5.7 setup for my academic project. I want to make medicine reminder project using laravel. 
For this I have 2 tables :

1. User
2. Medicine

I have models and controllers for User and Medicine.

- Controllers

  1. MedicineController
  2. UserController
  3. MedUserController
- Models

  1. User
  2. Medicine
  3. Med_User

In Model, User and Medicine have relation of Many-to-Many. And to maintain Many-to-Many I have linking table User_Medicine containing foreign key of both parent tables.

Now in controller, User adds medicine details and the app should check if the medicine is already in database. If medicine is already exists app should assign its med_id with user_id in linking table. But if medicine is not exist in db app should add new medicine detail. This process is written in MedUserController.

Now problem is, I have a function to add medicine in MedicineController@store. And I want to reuse that function from current controller ( MedUserController ).

What would be the best way to do that. Please suggest.

Comment: you can use the eloquent model to insert the medicine in MedUserController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A controller is meant to elaborate inputs and provide a response object. That being said, calling a controller from another controller is a bad practice.

In your case you should handle this with a [Repository Pattern](https://www.larashout.com/how-to-use-repository-pattern-in-laravel) meaning that you have a class responsible for creating/retrieving objects from the database, and you can call it from any controller/class.

This is a stub of what I would do

```
public function controllerAction() {
    $user = Auth::user();
    $medicineData = request()->all();
    $medicine = $this->medicineRepository->store($medicineData);
    $user->medicines()->attach($medicine);
}
```

In the `store` method of the repository you can check whether the medicine already exists or it's a new one, and you always return a `Medicine` object.

Comment: thank you for your help. This is what I was asking for. Thanks a lot :)